# Update() being called before loading scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 2 scenes in my game. A main home screen with a single button **Start** which clicking takes you to the other scene, and a scene with the game.

For some reason, `Update()` is being called on the 2nd scene even tho it hasn't been loaded yet.

```
public class StartClick : MonoBehaviour {
    public Button button;

    void Start() {
        button.onClick.AddListener(() => {
           SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your method of loading scene?

Comment: Added the method

Comment: Why is `Update()` being called on a scene that's not even loaded yet

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this image, Update is called AFTER input events, so that's why it's called once again (but should be just one more time).

[image]

Comment: That's not my question. What I'm trying to know is why is the 2nd Scene being loaded before the button is clicked

Comment: @AhmadUCG Then I suggest you to update your question, as it sounds like the problem is "Update() is being called on the 2nd scene even tho it hasn't been loaded yet."